# Open Email Desktop Client on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, hyperlink, html-email

I used

```
mailto:email@example.com
```

to open email to send mail. It worked in my Google chrome. But it is not working in other computers. Any alternate method to open mail from link??

Comment: Are you sure it's not working on any other computer? it's a per browser setting

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you compared the mail client settings between the computers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the mailto tag talks to the local API to open the default email client, regardless of the browser.

Comment: It also depends if you even have a mail client setup on your computer.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work. You can try going to `chrome://settings/handlers` and set value for `mailto:` to `none` instead of `gmail`

Answer (score 3):

It definitely should work with below html

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.com">email link</a>
```